# iPhone App: Dynamic Height of UITextView and elements under it

Tags: iphone, dynamic, height, textview

I have a view that has some labels in it with some info and textviews. I know a way to resize the textviews height that's not a problem. 
I just want to know if there is some simple way to move down all elements that are under the resized textview. Of course if I don't move them down, part of the resized textview is hidden under elements under it. 
I was hoping to find some property in the interface builder for position of each element like in css for websites, but couldn't find anything.
Thanks for any help :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try - (void)setNeedsLayout on the superview?

Comment: I'm noob in this iphone programming so no I didn't :), I'll check it out thanks!